# Closure as constructor?

Tags: ios, swift

I have seen an example on objc io book like this

```
callback(Result {
    if let e = error {
       throw e
    }

    guard let d = data else {
       throw NoDataError()
    }

    return try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: d)
})
```

where callback is

```
“callback: @escaping (Result<User, Error>) -> ()
```

It seems that Result, which is an enum type as defined by Swift is using a closure to create itself?

But i don see any documentation on this

Comment: In summary, initializer `Result.init(catching:)` converts a throwing expression into a `Result`. This code slightly abuse that by intentionally throwing results in some commong cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a documentation.

The expression represents the trailing closure syntax of the [init(catching:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result/3139399-init) method of [Result](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result). The description is

> Creates a new result by evaluating a throwing closure, capturing the returned value as a success, or any thrown error as a failure.

The full syntax is

```
callback(Result(catching: {
    if let e = error { 
       throw e 
    }

    guard let d = data else { 
       throw NoDataError() 
    }

    return try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: d)
    })
)
```

Please see also [Preserving the Results of a Throwing Expression](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result/preserving_the_results_of_a_throwing_expression)